# Attempting to GET Google Apps Single Sign-On Signing Key via API

Tags: google-provisioning-api, google-reseller-api, google-admin-settings-api

I'm receiving an interesting error from the Google Apps admin settings API when attempting to retrieve the Single Sign-On key for updating (creating) it the first time. We're looking to do this via the API only, but it appears as though the API is making the assumption the signing key has already been created client-side. The following GET request is failing with the error below:

```
GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/ruby-alphaz.co/sso/signingkey
```

The response error is as follows:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [error] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [errorCode] => 1408
                    [invalidInput] => 
                    [reason] => InvalidSsoSigningKey
                )
        )
)
```

I'm able to update Single Sign-On settings without a problem, but the signing key endpoint is causing problems. To be clear, no signing key currently exists for the domain, but the domain instructions are to attempt to retrieve the XML via the endpoint to ensure it has the proper id parameter set so I can follow up with a subsequent PUT response to create/update the signing key.

The documentation that I'm following as here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-settings/#retrieving_the_single_sign-on_signing_key

I know for a fact that my Auth token headers are set properly as they work for other endpoints.

Any ideas?

### Update (and Solution)

After conversing with Jay in the comments section of the below answer, it turns out the solution to the problem is as follows:

1. If you perform a GET request to `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/sso/signingkey` and receive an XML response with the `InvalidSsoSigningKey` error,  first ensure that you have enabled SSO via the `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/sso/general` endpoint.
2. If you're sure that you've enabled SSO and still receive the `InvalidSsoSigningKey` error, it is likely because you do not yet have an uploaded signing key. While it isn't readily documented, you may perform a PUT request to `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/sso/signingkey` with the following format to create your signing key:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006"> 
       <apps:property name="signingKey" value="[YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_CERTIFICATE_VALUE]" /> 
   </atom:entry>
   ```
3. From now on, you should be able to successfully issue GET requests to `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/sso/signingkey` and receive a valid response. Future updates will need to utilize this GET response as it contains the proper `id` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed an issue about this back in 2009, feel free to star it:

http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1527

You need to enable SSO in order to retrieve the key.

And yes, that means you can't check the key matches properly before enabling SSO.

You don't need to do the GET before doing the PUT. Just create the XML manually. See how GAM does it:

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/source/browse/trunk/gdata/apps/adminsettings/service.py#363

Comment: Thanks for the post Jay. I can verify that I have indeed already verified SSO via an API call to `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/sso/general`. I have not, however, uploaded a certificate.

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't you expect to get an error when you attempt to GET a certificate that hasn't been uploaded yet? Why are you trying to GET the certificate before you upload it?

Comment: I'm attempting to retrieve the necessary empty XML response for the purpose of creating one via the API call. The documentation seemingly indicates you can request the response XML which would contain an empty field for population in a returned PUT request (which should also give me a unique identifying ID field necessary for the PUT request).

Comment: In summary, my expected response is the scaffolded XML outlined by the API docs so I can issue a PUT request to create a new signing key.

Comment: see my updated answer, you don't need to GET first, just manually generate the XML for the PUT.

Comment: The docs only specify that an AtomPub feed is returned with a successful response. They don't specify what is returned with an error, other than the HTTP status code.

Comment: I had actually previously tried the PUT request by itself and received the same error: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
<apps:property name="signingKey" value="' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->_config['publicSSOKey'])) . '" />
</atom:entry>`. I have both a dsaprivkey.pem and rsaprivkey.pem file and tried with the contents of the dsaprivkey.pem file.

Comment: Also, as a quick aside, is there any chance I should just be supplying the base64 encoded values contained inside of the file between `-----BEGIN[A-Z\s]+-----` and `-----END[A-Z\s]+-----`? That's likely the PUT culprit if so, as I'm manually base64 encoding the entirety of the file.

Comment: Your supposed to upload the public key, not the private key.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I'm now getting a successful response by just using the following scenario: 1) Attempt GET, check for error response. 2) If error response matches InvalidSsoSigningKey, generate a PUT request with custom XML utilizing dsacert.pem signing key file.